# C# Threading; Different results from IDE when Ran

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to better my understand of threading in C# 5. 
I have the following code which gives me different results if I press F5 (a and b appear to get to 10) or I press CTRL F5 (a and b get to 3, as per the text in the book I am studying)... can someone please explain why? Also, I don't understand why this stops at 10 for each thread as it doesn't seem to have any sort of limit on it. Is it possible someone can explain this to me?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace _70483.Chapter1
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static ThreadLocal<int> _field =
            new ThreadLocal<int>(() =>
            {
                return Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            });

        public static void Main()
        {
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < _field.Value; x++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Thread A: {0}", x);
                }
            }).Start();

            new Thread(() =>
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < _field.Value; x++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Thread B: {0}", x);
                }
            }).Start();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: from which book? i myself was having similar situation

Comment: "it doesn't seem to have any sort of limit on it" - that's what `x < _field.Value` is

Comment: As stated in my own comment. I hope the book guides you to a better suited facility for multithreading: System.Threading.Task

Comment: This is in the official "Programming in C# - Exam Ref 70-483"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well on my machine in debug B get to 10 and A to 9.
In release without the debugger it is 2 and 3.

Nothing magic here. You are using thread local data which uses the ManagedThreadId which is just a number identifying the thread.

In debug you can see plenty threads for the application:

```
Not Flagged     14280   0   Worker Thread   <No Name>       Highest
Not Flagged     6180    3   Worker Thread   <No Name>       Normal
Not Flagged     4364    0   Worker Thread   <No Name>       Normal
Not Flagged     5484    7   Worker Thread   vshost.RunParkingWindow [Managed to Native Transition]  Normal
Not Flagged     4040    8   Worker Thread   .NET SystemEvents   [Managed to Native Transition]  Normal
Not Flagged     6688    9   Main Thread Main Thread MT.Program.Main Normal
Not Flagged >   13472   10  Worker Thread   <No Name>   MT.Program..cctor.AnonymousMethod__4    Normal
Not Flagged     12240   11  Worker Thread   <No Name>   MT.Program.Main.AnonymousMethod__1  Normal
```

In release the vshosting process is not attached and some of the other threads are not present there too, therefore you get a much smaller thread id but you should never get A and B to be the same

Comment: Indeed - I just copied the code as-is and my A and B always iterated to different values.

Comment: Could they be the same number if Thread A finished before Thread B was even started?

Comment: Basically yes but this is unlikely here however I am a little confused of the generated output. I would have expected it to be interwoven Console.Writelines from A and B but they seem to be linear. Anyway I would suggest to move along to System.Threading.Task as they are way better in many situations.

Comment: The book probably gets around to that, but this is a poor example to show off `ThreadLocal` or `ManagedThreadId` if it is direct from book.